# Multiple whereEqualTo condition in FirebaseFirestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hi so I have this exact db schema where there are documents with a field called "status", this field has different values, it can be "pending", "sent" and etc..

I have a FirebaseUI Recycler and I want to load all documents that contain that 2 values. So far I've tried this code:

```
Query query = fStore.collection("friendRequests").document(currentUID)
            .collection("userFriendRequest")
            .whereEqualTo("status", "pending") //1 condition
            .whereEqualTo("status", "sent"); //2 condition
```

But I'm having trouble with that since it doesn't return nothing , I've tried with arrays but I couldn't make it work aswell.

Question: Any idea where I'm missing?

Pictures of the schema:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query is an AND condition, and it wont work since a field in one document cannot have two values, you can do the following:

```
Query query = fStore.collection("friendRequests").document(currentUID)
            .collection("userFriendRequest")
            whereIn("status", Arrays.asList("pending", "sent");
```

> Use the in operator to combine up to 10 equality (==) clauses on the same field with a logical OR. An in query returns documents where the given field matches any of the comparison values

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any